# conditional rounding function in R negated by dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, rounding-error

I am trying to produce a table for a manuscript. For this table, there are NA values, large values above 1,000, and values that are below 10.

I'd like the numbers less than 10 to be rounded to 1 decimal point, and the numbers greater than 10 to be rounded to nearest whole number.  I'll use the kable formatting to show commas for 'big.marks'.

It looks like when I include the print(f2[j,i]) in the for loop, the numbers appear as they should (i.e. <10 has a 1 decimal, >10 rounded to the nearest whole number).

However, when I look at dataframe f2 after the for loop all values show 1 decimal, even if they are above 10.

Subsequently, when using kable, the values all show 1 decimal place.

Thanks for your help!!

Here is a reproduce-able example.

```
f2<-data.frame(HEALTH=c("Heart","Head","Back","Hands","Eyes","Feet"),
               NO2   =c(2001.13, NA, 15.88, 0.832, 0.21111, 100),
               SO2   =c(NA, 300.1450, 1.550, 2.04, 3.99, NA),
               O3    =c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.115, 100.13))

custom_round <- function(a) {
  if(is.na(a)) {b <- NA}
  else if(abs(a) < 10) {
    b <- round(as.numeric(a), digits = 1)
  } else if(abs(a) >= 10) {
    b <-round(as.numeric(a), digits = 0)
  }
  return(b)
}


for( i in c(2:ncol(f2))){
  for (j in c(1:nrow(f2))){
    f2[j,i] <- custom_round(a = f2[j,i])
    print(f2[j,i])
  }
}


kable(f2, format = "html",
      booktabs = TRUE,
      escape = FALSE,
      col.names = (c("Health effect", "cases/yr","cost/yr","treatment/yr")) ,
      align=c("l","r","r","r"),
      format.args = list(big.mark = ','),
      linesep="") %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options= c("HOLD_position"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally the numerics are printed with the same number of decimal places in each element of a vector, so you may need to convert the table columns to character to get the behaviour you want. One way to do this would be:

```
custom_round <- function(a) {
  if(is.na(a)) {b <- NA}
  else if(abs(a) < 10) {
    b <- round(as.numeric(a), digits = 1)
  } else if(abs(a) >= 10) {
    b <-round(as.numeric(a), digits = 0)
  }
  return(as.character(b))  #modify return type to preserve formatting
}

f2_c <- f2  #character version of data

for( i in c(2:ncol(f2))){
  for (j in c(1:nrow(f2))){
    f2_c[j,i] <- custom_round(a = f2[j,i])
    print(f2_c[j,i])
  }
}


kable(f2_c, format = "html",
      booktabs = TRUE,
      escape = FALSE,
      col.names = (c("Health effect", "cases/yr","cost/yr","treatment/yr")) ,
      align=c("l","r","r","r"),
      format.args = list(big.mark = ','),
      linesep="") %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options= c("HOLD_position"))
```